# Why does useState not increment

Tags: reactjs, react-native, use-state

I'm trying to implement useState to store an incrementing value. When I try incrementing the value it doesn't update it. I have tried manually setting the value to a specific number and this does work. What is wrong?

```
const [cardsIndex, setCardsIndex] = useState(0);

       <Card style={[styles.card, styles.card1]} key={index}
          onSwipedRight={(event) => { setCardsIndex(cardsIndex+1);}}
          onSwipedLeft={(event) => { setCardsIndex(cardsIndex+1);}}
       >
```

Comment: Can you do some step-through debugging or add a console.log in the actual event handlers? What is `cardsIndex` at the time you call `setCardsIndex` ?

Comment: I tried running console.log and this value didn't increment at all when the onSwipedRight and Left functions were run.

Comment: Where are you getting the `Card` component?

Comment: It's not relevant

Answer (score 8):

Whenever you want to update the state based on previous value of the state then you must use a function in setState.

i.e.

```
setCardsIndex((prevValue) => prevValue + 1)
```

Docs:
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates

Comment: Is this a new requirement?

Comment: No. It's the recommended way of updating state based on previous state value

Comment: Some tutorials use the way I added. I guess that must not be allowed anymore.

Comment: You can do like that but in that case it is not guaranteed that you will get the latest value of the state.

Comment: This has been the case at least since 2019, even for class components. https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous

Answer (score 0):

**Just change  :**

```
onSwipedRight={(event) => { setCardsIndex(cardsIndex+1);}}
onSwipedLeft={(event) => { setCardsIndex(cardsIndex+1);}}
```

**to :**

```
onSwipedRight={(event) => {() => { setCardsIndex(cardsIndex =>cardsIndex+1);}}
onSwipedLeft={(event) => { () => { setCardsIndex(cardsIndex =>cardsIndex+1);}}}
```